# Making firebase's sendPasswordResetEmail more secure

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

On a website using firebase that contains auth I'm implementing a "forgot password" feature.

The return status of `sendPasswordResetEmail()` is 400 if the user supplies an email that doesn't have an account associated with it. It returns 200 if the email does have an account.

That means that an attacker can keep guessing emails until they get a 200. Then they know of a valid email. Then they can start guessing passwords for it.

Is there a way to get `sendPasswordResetEmail()` to always return 200? I'll like the only response, whether a good or bad email is entered, to be "Check your email for a reset link". If the email is invalid then firebase should quietly not send an email.

Or is there some other mechanism that would increase security?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*firebaser here*

API calls from client-side SDKs to Firebase Authentication are rate-limited to reduce the risk in such a dictionary attacks. We also just launched new configuration options that allow you to [enable email enumeration protection](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/password-auth#enumeration-protection) for example by always returning `INVALID_LOGIN_CREDENTIALS` regardless of the type of error.

If you suspect you're project is actively seeing such an attack, [reach out to Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) so they can investigate and adjust quota if needed.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I don't suspect that attack is happening but I don't know what clue I would have if it were. But I especially don't know what clue my client would have after I deliver the website to them. I guess I'll just hope no one wants to hack the site.

Comment: I just checked with engineering, and they are apparently working to add some controls around email enumeration attacks (I just learned that term from reading their docs). I'll update here when there are any updates around that, which may actually be quite soon. :)

Comment: I added a link to the documentation for the new feature in my answer.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Thank you for you help. You said "The specific API isn't mentioned there yet, as it just landed, but I think it should probably work." But I didn't found a way to update the config for old firebase Authentification despite identitytoolkit as I'm using firebase. 

Comment: then I will plan 1 or 2 days to upgrade the authentification system if there is no other solution

Comment: There should be an upgrade banner within the Firebase console at the bottom of this page: https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/_/authentication/providers